# Dojo events not triggering

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, dom-events

I have a Dojo tab-container and when I click on certain buttons, a new tab is added dynamically with its contents downloaded via Ajax. The tabs contain dynamic form elements which are parsed and loaded by Dojo just fine. I am also including Javascript blocks which are specific for each tab and those are downloaded as well via Ajax... however, none of the Javascript blocks execute!

Example of tab content:

```
<input id="test" name="test" type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   dojo.connect(dijit.byId('test'), 'onClick', function(evt){
       alert('testing 123');
   });
</script>
```

However, if I do this instead the events trigger just fine:

```
<input id="test" name="test" type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox">
    <script type="dojo/method" event='onClick'>
         alert('testing 123');
    </script>
</input>
```

My question is, why don't Javascript blocks in the first example work? is this a Dojo limitation? Also, I am also trying to set properties and values for the widgets AFTER they've been loaded. How do i active that given I have to use something like `dojo.addOnLoad()` which won't work because it requires a Javascript block and that doesn't work as per the first example... There is no equivalent widget onLoad event so I can't use the second method either... Any ideas how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "tab content" is actually a *Content Pane* element. You can't call a javascript inside a content pane unless you use `<script type="dojo/method">`. At least this is what I know.

**Update:** ifyou'll use `dojox.layout.ContentPane` instead of the `dijit.layout.ContentPane` all the problems regarding the js inside it will vanish. From Dojo Reference Guide:

> dojox.layout.ContenPane is an extension to dijit.layout.ContentPane providing script execution, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use dojo.hitch so that your function will be in scope when it is actually called. Try using:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('test'), 'onCLick', dojo.hitch(this, function(evt) {
      alert('testing123');
}));
```

You can read more about it here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/hitch.html#dojo-hitch

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that the widget has been parsed first. Do it like so :

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){/*connect code*/});
```